# Objective C - declaring optional field on property

Tags: objective-c

Is there any work around to set Bool and float types to Optional in objective c i couldn't find any?

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) float percentageOfCases;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) float inspectionPercentageOfCases;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString<Optional> *inspectionStatus;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL sendNotification;
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift's `Optional` corresponds to nullability in Objective-C, and in Objective-C, only pointer types can be nullable. So you have to change your properties to be pointer types, which in this case means `NSNumber *` for the `float` properties and either `NSNumber *` or `CFBooleanRef` for the `BOOL` property.

However, changing the types will make Swift import the properties as `NSNumber` and `CFBoolean` instead of as `Float` and `Bool`. So you probably also want to apply `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` to each property, and a Swift `extension` to define properties of type `Float` and `Bool`. Here's what it looks like:

```objectivec
// In your Objective-C header:

@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign, nullable) NSNumber *percentageOfCases NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
@property (nonatomic, assign, nullable) NSNumber *inspectionPercentageOfCases NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
@property (nonatomic, assign, nullable) NSString *inspectionStatus;
@property (nonatomic, assign, nullable) CFBooleanRef sendNotification NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
@end
```

```swift
extension MyObject {
    var percentageOfCases: Float? {
        get { __percentageOfCases?.floatValue }
        set { __percentageOfCases = newValue as NSNumber? }
    }

    var inspectionPercentageOfCases: Float? {
        get { __inspectionPercentageOfCases?.floatValue }
        set { __inspectionPercentageOfCases = newValue as NSNumber? }
    }

    var sendNotification: Bool? {
        get { (__sendNotification as NSNumber?)?.boolValue }
        set { __sendNotification = newValue as NSNumber? }
    }
}
```

Note that Xcode will **not** offer code completion for the double-underscored identifiers (like `__percentageOfCases`).

Comment: Does `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` cause the `__*` properties, or is there something else at play here? I'm not seeing where `__percentageOfCases` sneaks in.

Comment: Yes, when Swift sees the `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` annotation, it adds the `__` prefix. See [“Improving Objective-C API Declarations for Swift”](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/improving_objective-c_api_declarations_for_swift).

Comment: Oooohhhhh… TIL.